# ZingChartMaps ZC is not defined

Tags: angular, dictionary, zingchart

I am testing ZingCharts for Angular with a small local project.  I am having trouble with getting the ZingChartMap to work.  All other ZingCharts work as expected.  Currently, I am working with Angular 12.  Where I am having trouble is with JS files zingchart-maps.min.js and zingchart-maps-usa.min.js.  Something in them is causing an error.  I am using zingchart-angular 1.0.9.  Anyone familiar with the below error and know how to resolve?

core.js:6498 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: ZC is not defined ReferenceError: ZC is not defined at Object.6272 (zingchart-maps.min.js:8:1)

Answer (score 0):

I found three solutions that could work.  #1 is the prefered solution

1. I needed to import ZingChartAngular module before the FeatureModuleRouting Module.  Good practice is to place @angular modules first, third party modules second, and local modules last.
2. I needed to import the ZingChartAngular module to the app.module.ts file and the feature module ts file.
3. I needed to import ZingChartAngular module to the feature module ts file, and only export the ZingChartAngular module in app.module.ts.